# If you had to point to polymorphism, which line would it be?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

So, lets say we have a couple of classes:

- First one is interface class, called "Messenger".
- In the second class "MessengerEx", we inherit "Messenger" interface
  and realize its methods.
- And also, we have "main" class.

Lets say that main looks like this:

```
// initialization of main class`
Messenger messengerEx = new MessengerEx();
system.out.println(messengerEx.getSomeMessage());
// ending main
```

If someone asked you to point where polymorphism in this program is, where would you point?

Comment: There is only one line of code in that code.

Comment: I'll point to the same line you mentioned.

Comment: @azurefrog - I am asking a general question. There is no need to look for a code. Messenger interface has, lets say, a couple of defined methods. MesserngerEx just prints out some message for those methods. And in main, we just create an object. If it help, I will edit it and throw a couple of method callers in order to populate main a little bit more.

Comment: `I am asking a general question` That would then likely make this not suitable for SO.

Comment: If all you want is general information, there are [many](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), [many](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm), [many](http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-guide-to-polymorphism-in-java/) ways to learn about polymorphism, just from a quick search on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `MessengerEx` subtypes the interface `Messenger` which is [sub-type polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping).

Comment: Thank you :) I  understand that it is a sub-type polymorphism, I just wanted to make sure that I understand the main idea.